# How to pass AD computer names to array?

Tags: arrays, powershell, object, foreach, active-directory

I am trying to Set-ADComputer on all machines matching the filter that is added to the $servers array. But it's not working. I guess it has something to do with passing an object to a string, but I can't get my head around it. Anyone's got a golden tip?

```
#Get gateway
$gateway = "MGMT01"
$gatewayObject = Get-ADComputer -Identity $gateway

#Get servers
$servers=@(Get-ADComputer -Filter {OperatingSystem -like "Windows Server*"}   -Properties Name | select name | ft -HideTableHeaders)

#Create list of servers
Out-File -FilePath c:\adcomputers.txt -InputObject $servers

#Set WAC delegation
ForEach ($server in $servers)
{
$nodeObject = Get-ADComputer -Identity $server
Set-ADComputer -Identity $nodeObject -PrincipalsAllowedToDelegateToAccount $gatewayObject
}
```

### Errors:

Get-ADComputer : Cannot bind parameter 'Identity'. Cannot convert the "Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEndData" value of type "Microsoft.PowerShell.C
ommands.Internal.Format.FormatEndData" to type "Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADComputer".

At C:\Users\SA.****\Desktop\inventorize-honolulu-incl-sso.ps1:7 char:40
+ $nodeObject = Get-ADComputer -Identity $server
+                                        ~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ADComputer], ParameterBindingException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADComputer

Set-ADComputer : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'. The argument is null. Provide a valid value for the argument, and then try running the command again.

At C:\Users\SA.****\Desktop\inventorize-honolulu-incl-sso.ps1:8 char:26
+ Set-ADComputer -Identity $nodeObject -PrincipalsAllowedToDelegateToAc ...
+                          ~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Set-ADComputer], ParameterBindingValidationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.SetADComputer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To output your list of servers to a text file, all you need is this:

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter {OperatingSystem -like "Windows Server*"} |
  Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name |
  Out-File "c:\adcomputers.txt"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, though I don't have any problems generating the .txt file.

The error concerns the ForEach loop. Where the queried computer names, don't pass to the -identity parameter.

Comment: Actually your existing code for generating the text file is not correct: We don't use `ft` (alias of `Format-Table`) to output to a text file (hence my answer).

Answer (score 1):

Bill_Stewart had the right idea, it just didn't fit in exactly with the way you're doing things.

It's the `ft -HideTableHeaders` that's messing up your array. Use `select -ExpandProperty` instead:

```
$servers=@(Get-ADComputer -Filter {OperatingSystem -like "Windows Server*"}   -Properties Name | select -ExpandProperty name)
```

That will give you an array of plain strings, as you seem to want.

Comment: Thank you for putting in those words. Indeed it runs with that edit. Thank you both Gabriel and @Bill_Stewart. I'll look into the use of -ExpandProperty.

Answer (score 0):

Your Get-ADComputer line is an expression problem, you are missing () in {}. Your example works fine after fixing that.

```
$servers=@(Get-ADComputer -Filter {(OperatingSystem -like "Windows Server*")} -Properties Name | select name | ft -HideTableHeaders)
```